# Capturing web camvideo from Open CV

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I'm testing out some code I found to capture the web cam video stream, it's quite different from what I used to do for achieving the same but it's supposed to be the *appropiate* way for doing it.

This is the way I **used to do**:

```
CvCapture* capture;
IplImage* frame = 0;

while (true)
{
    //Read the video stream
    capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(1);
    if (! capture) break;
    frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);

    //Create a window to display 
    cvNamedWindow("Te estas viendo", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL|CV_WINDOW_KEEPRATIO);

    cvShowImage("Te estas viendo", frame);

    int c = cvWaitKey(10);
    if ( (char)c == 27 ) break;
}

//Clean and release resources
cvReleaseImage(&frame);
cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

This is the **testing code**:

```
VideoCapture camera;
camera.open(cameraNumber);
if (!camera.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "ERROR: Could not access the camera or video!" <<endl;
    exit(1);
}

while (true) {
    // Grab the next camera frame.
    cv::Mat cameraFrame;
    camera >> cameraFrame;
    if (cameraFrame.empty()) {
    std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't grab a camera frame." <<
    std::endl;
    exit(1);
}
```

I'm not getting the first error line, so it's supposed to be opening the camera, but always failing at grabbing camera frames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could be missing the closing bracket in your while loop. Also make sure that you create `namedWindow` outside the `while` loop. Creating the window at every iteration is expensive. See below:

```
VideoCapture camera;
camera.open(cameraNumber);
namedWindow("output");

if (!camera.isOpened()) {
    cerr << "ERROR: Could not access the camera or video!" <<endl;
    return -1;
}

while (true) {
    // Grab the next camera frame.
    cv::Mat cameraFrame;
    camera >> cameraFrame;
    if (cameraFrame.empty()) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't grab a camera frame." <<
            std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    imshow("output", cameraFrame);
    waitKey(10);
}
```

Comment: I keep obtaining the `"ERROR: Couldn't grab a camera frame."``message.

Comment: believe Alexey in any case. what did you feed in for "cameraNumber" ? -1 (any available) should be a good idea, 0 ( the 1st ) the next best, try around. and - definitely prefer the c++ api ( as in your 2nd example ) to the old c one !

Comment: I think it's related to this, but I can't find a way to fix it. Or Dunno if I should downgrade

Answer (score 1):

Find more informatiion about [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture-videocapture). Parameter `device` is ID of the opened video capturing device, and pass `0` if there is only one camera on your computer. Here is a code I have tested to capture video from webcam. Tell me if there is any problem.

```
#include <cv.h>
#include <highgui.h>
using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Mat cameraFrame;
    VideoCapture camera(0);
    if (!camera.isOpened()) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR: Could not access the camera or video!" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }
    while (true) {
        // Grab the next camera frame.  
        camera >> cameraFrame;
        if (cameraFrame.empty()) {
            std::cerr << "ERROR: Couldn't grab a camera frame." <<
            std::endl;
            return -1;
        }
        namedWindow("camera", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("camera", cameraFrame);
        char ch = waitKey(25);              
        if (ch == 27) break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What Open CV version did you use on it?

Comment: @Diego I use version 2.4.6 and it works fine for me. It might be the problem with OpenCV install, hard to say.

Comment: @Diego On Windows with OpenCV ver. 2.4.6 (installed using CMake)

Comment: Interesting, I didn't really used CMake,  I just extracted Open CV to my hard drive, added `C:\opencv\build\x64\vc11\bin` to my path and then the appropiate settings to bind the library in Visual Studio.

Comment: @Diego You said the code worked on 2.4.5, so did you figure out whether the problem involved with OpenCV installation: try some simple code (on 2.4.6) such as loading an image from files. If it also has no problems, replace the test code with my code above.

Comment: @WangYudong how is your code example different from my answer?